# Is there a way to create a script that cuts specific strips in specific intervals in the VSE?

Tags: animation, scripting, video-sequence-editor, video

What I have is a strip of an image. And I decided to take a "Scratch" approach, which would entail me having to cut each frame to move it to a specific position (x + 1 per frame) to give off the illusion of 'movement'.

Is there a way to script such a task so that the strips would be cut at x intervals and be moved + x px at every interval?

Comment: Search for "Sprite Sheet" animation, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lb0pW3_jWlo

Comment: It was very informative, however, I have a concern. What I would prefer to achieve is a 'slide' effect, which would mean that the image moves x pixels every x intervals. Would the same concept apply?

Comment: Yes, you can do something similar. If you expand your question so we can better understand what you're trying to achieve we can write better answers.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and sorry for the more incoherent babbling earlier, it is 4:44 in the a.m. where I live, so I am already a bit sleepy. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Properly, you can use Transform Tools and some keyframes to dom the movement. Here's the add-on: https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools

Comment: Do you have some reference (mockup) of desired result? As intuition mentioned it could be achieved in different way. From your description it is not clear for me yet. Split per frame OK, but move each frame on X? it is still image not video strip right? And move on x+1 you mean in screen not in timeline, right?